# jquery placeholder function: When the input is empty, placeholder value is sent

Tags: jquery

I wrote a placeholder function in jquery which works fine, but when the field is empty it actually has the placeholder's value. I solved it outside the function, I check it in the sendForm() function upon submit. But I want to resolve it inside the placeholder function to make it work for all cases. 
Here is the code:

**jquery placeholder:**

```
$(":input[data-placeholder]").each(function(index){     

    if ($(this).val() == "")                
    {
        $(this).val($(this).data("placeholder"));           
        $(this).addClass("placeholder");            
    }           
    }).live("focus",function(){
        //check if the field not filled
        if($(this).hasClass("placeholder")) 
        {
            $(this).removeClass("placeholder");
            $(this).val("");
        }
    }).live("blur",function(){      
        if($(this).val()=="")
        {
            $(this).val($(this).data("placeholder"));           
            $(this).addClass("placeholder");                
        }

    });
```

**html:**

```
            <form name="forme" method="post" onsubmit="return sendForm();"> 
                <div id="fields">                   
                    <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" data-placeholder="שם מלא"/>
                    <input type="text" name="userPhone" id="userPhone" data-placeholder="טלפון"/>
                    <input type="text" name="userMail" id="userMail" data-placeholder='דוא"ל'/>
                     <!--<textarea name="userMail" id="userMail" data-placeholder='דוא"ל'></textarea>-->
                </div>
                <input type="submit" id="submit" value="הרשמה">
            </form>
```

**sendForm():**

```
function sendForm(){

var uname, uphone, umail; 
$("#userName").hasClass("placeholder") ? uname="" : uname=$("#userName").val(); 
$("#userPhone").hasClass("placeholder") ? uphone="" : uphone=$("#userPhone").val(); 
$("#userMail").hasClass("placeholder") ? umail="" : umail=$("#userMail").val(); 

var dataObject = {name: uname, phone: uphone, mail: umail};

if(validate(uname,uphone,umail))
{
```

Comment: What browsers do you have to support? Perhaps you could use the [placeholder](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_placeholder.asp) attribute.

Answer (score 3):

**jQuery Placeholder (added on submit for your placeholder):**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(':input[data-placeholder]').each(function(index){
        if($(this).val() == ''){
            $(this).val($(this).data('placeholder'));
            $(this).addClass('placeholder');
        }
        $(this).closest('form').submit(function(){
            $(':input[data-placeholder]').each(function(){
                if($(this).hasClass('placeholder')){
                    $(this).removeClass('placeholder');
                    $(this).val('');
                    //console.log($(this));
                }
            });
        });
    }).live('focus', function(){
        //check if the field not filled
        if($(this).hasClass('placeholder')){
            $(this).removeClass('placeholder');
            $(this).val('');
        }
    }).live('blur', function(){
        if($(this).val() == ''){
            $(this).val($(this).data('placeholder'));
            $(this).addClass('placeholder');
        }
    });
});
```

**CSS style for Placeholder:**

```
.placeholder{color:#a0a0a0;}
```

First thing after the DOM is `.ready` is running a loop for all input tag which have the attribute `data-placeholder`.

Then, it's checking if there is no value in the input, and search for the closest `form` tag with [jQuery.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) function (method), which is working the way up the DOM until it's find zero or one element `jQuery.closest('form')` [(unlike jQuery.patents() )](http://api.jquery.com/parents/).

And then, you're already written code keep running.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an `onsubmit` handler to each element's form in your `.each()` loop:

```
var form = $(this).closest('form');
// check if onsubmit handler is not already installed for this form
if (!form.data('placeholder-processed')) {
    form.data('placeholder-processed', true);
    form.on('submit', function() {
        // move your sendForm() logic here
    }
}
```

Note that your `.each()` loop will process all *existing* elements at the moment you run it, but your `.live()` event handlers will also trigger for `input[data-placeholder]` elements created *after* you have run the `.each()`.